# How to ask for user input after a thread execution in C

Tags: c, multithreading

I am trying to learn multithreading in C and also "replicating" the command line. on a particular command "marquee", I aim to use multithreading because this requires to move the string from left to right. However, upon trying to execute a thread, I noticed that the output when I use marquee is this:

[threading image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSwfN.png)

it prints the output of the function with the "MyOS>" line.

this is the example of my code:

```
//Creating the marquee requirements (this is just a trial to see the error)
void try(void *a){
    
    printf("this is the second thread\n");
    
}


int main(){
    
    char command[COMMAND_SIZE] = {0};
    time_t t;
    time(&t);
    char pwd[FILENAME_MAX];
    GetCurrentDir(pwd, FILENAME_MAX);
    pthread_t thread1;

    do{
        printf("MyOS>");
        fgets(command,sizeof(command), stdin);
        

        if(strncmp(command, "say", 3) == 0) {
            printf("%s", command+4);
        }else if(strncmp(command, "cls", 3) == 0){
            system("clear");
        }else if(strncmp(command, "time", 4) == 0){
            printf("%s", ctime(&t));
        }else if(strncmp(command, "pwd", 3) == 0){
            printf("%s\n", pwd);
        }
        else if(strncmp(command, "marquee", 6) == 0){
             pthread_t thread1;
             pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,try,NULL);
             pthread_join(&thread1, NULL);      
        }
    } while (strncmp(command, "exit", 4));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `pthread_join` call is wrong. First arg should be `thread1`. Change that and it should print as expected.

Comment: Also, please post the text output in the question as text and not as an image.

Comment: Another thing, probably should call `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf("MyOS>");` to ensure the shell prompt is printed. Because `printf` is line buffered and may not acutally show the output until a newline or an explicit flush.